# Crash when delete 2D pointer matrices[Heap corruption detected]

Tags: c++, matrix, visual-studio-2015

I randomly created two matrices A0 and A1 with a random size. After that, I copy these two matrices to A01 matrix such as

```
[A0 | 0 ]
[0  | A1]
```

Finaly, I delete the memory of them. However, I only run about 3-5 times, after that, the program detect the error such as

[image]

I am using visual studio 2015. What is happen in my code? Is is wrong to delete the pointer matrices?

This is my full code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>       /* time */
#define random(x) (rand()%x)
typedef unsigned char  U8;
typedef unsigned int   U32;
void create_and_delete_matrix()
{
    U32 M0,M1,M01;
    U32 m_L0,m_L1,m_L01;
    U32 range = 20;
    M0   = random(range) + 1;
    m_L0 = random(range) + 1;
    M1   = random(range) + 1;
    m_L1 = random(range) + 1;
    M01  = M0 + M1;
    m_L01 = m_L0 + m_L1;

    U8** A0 = new U8*[M0];
    U8** A1 = new U8*[M1];
    U8** A01 = new U8*[M01];
    //***********For A0***********//
    for (U32 i = 0; i < M0; ++i){
        A0[i] = new U8[m_L0];
        memset(A0[i], 0, m_L0*sizeof(U8));
    }
    //***********For A1***********//
    for (U32 i = 0; i < M1; ++i) {
        A1[i] = new U8[m_L1];
        memset(A1[i], 0, m_L1*sizeof(U8));
    }
    //***********For A01***********//
    for (U32 i = 0; i < M01; ++i) {
        A01[i] = new U8[m_L01];
        memset(A01[i], 0, m_L01*sizeof(U8));
    }

    //***********Set random data A0 and A1***********//
    for (U32 i = 0; i < M0; ++i) {
        for (U32 j = 0; j < m_L0; ++j) {
            A0[i][j] = random(2);
            printf("%d ", A0[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    for (U32 i = 0; i < M1; ++i) {
        for (U32 j = 0; j < m_L1; ++j) {
            A1[i][j] = random(2);
            printf("%d ", A1[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    //***********Copy A0 and A1 to A01 ***********//
    //***********--------------------- ***********//
    //***********------[A0 | 0 ]-------***********//
    //***********------[0  | A1]-------***********//
    //***********--------------------- ***********//
    for (U32 i = 0; i < M0; ++i){
        //A0 to A01
        memcpy(A01[i] + m_L0, A0[i], m_L0 * sizeof(U8));
    }
    for (U32 i = 0; i < M1; ++i){
        // A1 to A01
        memcpy(A01[i + M0] + m_L0, A1[i], m_L1 * sizeof(U8));
    }
    //**********Print result of A01**********//
    for (U32 i = 0; i < M01; ++i) {
        for (U32 j = 0; j < m_L01; ++j) {
            printf("%d ", A01[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    //free A0, A1, A01 matrix
    for (U32 i = 0; i < M0; ++i){
        if (i < m_L0){
            delete[] A0[i];
            A0[i] = NULL;
        }
    }
    delete[] A0;
    A0 = NULL;

    for (U32 i = 0; i < M1; ++i) {
        if (i < m_L1) {
            delete[] A1[i];
            A1[i] = NULL;
        }
    }
    delete[] A1;
    A1 = NULL;

    for (U32 i = 0; i < M01; ++i) {
        if (i < m_L01) {
            delete[] A01[i];
            A01[i] = NULL;
        }
    }
    delete[] A01;
    A01 = NULL;

}
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    unsigned int time_ui = static_cast<unsigned int>(time(NULL));
    srand(time_ui);
    for (U32 iter = 0; iter < 100; iter++){
        create_and_delete_matrix();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is [live demo code](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_cpp11_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMSHlkS19JeW4yUWc)

I also tested in Ubuntu with g++ and the error is

```
*** Error in `main': free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x0000000001a58600 ***                                                      
======= Backtrace: =========                                                                                                       
/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x7850e)[0x7ff6e22d750e]                                                                                         
/lib64/libc.so.6(cfree+0x5b5)[0x7ff6e22e3165]                                                                                      
main[0x40107b]                                                                                                                     
main[0x401105]                                                                                                                     
/lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf0)[0x7ff6e227efe0]                                                                           
main[0x400939]                                                                                                                     
======= Memory map: ========                                                                                                       
00400000-00402000 r-xp 00000000 fd:198 59464901                          /home/cg/root/main                                        
00601000-00602000 r--p 00001000 fd:198 59464901                          /home/cg/root/main                                        
00602000-00603000 rw-p 00002000 fd:198 59464901                          /home/cg/root/main
```

Comment: You've already run your code through a debugger, right? Also, while you use `new[]` and `delete[]`, this is more or less C99, not C++.

Comment: Yes. I run both debug in visual studio 2015 and g++ in Ubuntu via Kdevelop

Comment: Sorry. I will clean it. But it still got error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is here

```
for (U32 i = 0; i < M0; ++i){
    //A0 to A01
    memcpy(A01[i] + m_L0, A0[i], m_L0 * sizeof(U8));
}
for (U32 i = 0; i < M1; ++i){
    // A1 to A01
    memcpy(A01[i + M0] + m_L0, A1[i], m_L1 * sizeof(U8));
}
```

It should be

```
for (U32 i = 0; i < M0; ++i){
    //A0 to A01
    memcpy(A01[i], A0[i], m_L0 * sizeof(U8));
}
for (U32 i = 0; i < M1; ++i){
    // A1 to A01
    //After m_L0 elements
    memcpy(A01[i] + m_L0, A1[i], m_L1 * sizeof(U8));
}
```

Or you can copy element wise which will make it more readable.

Moreover, here

```
for (U32 i = 0; i < M0; ++i){
    A0[i] = new U8[m_L0];
}
for (U32 i = 0; i < M0; ++i){
    A0[i] = new U8[m_L0];
    memset(A0[i], 0, m_L0*sizeof(U8));
}
//***********For A1***********//
for (U32 i = 0; i < M1; ++i){
    A1[i] = new U8[m_L1];
}
for (U32 i = 0; i < M1; ++i) {
    A1[i] = new U8[m_L1];
    memset(A1[i], 0, m_L1*sizeof(U8));
}
```

you are creating memory leaks. First loop is not required. Rather use initializer to initialize with 0 if possible.

To avoid memory management here, you can use `std::vector` with `reserve`.

**Edit**
For free, it must be complement to your allocation:

```
for (U32 i = 0; i < M1; ++i) {
    delete [] A0[i];
}

delete [] A0;
```

Comment: Yes. It is right. I was wrong to copy A0 to A01. Sorry. How about my free matrix function?

Comment: Free matrix seems fine, just run i from 0 to required limit, not if check inside the loop.

Comment: Can you show me your code which talk about " run i from 0 to required limit, not if check inside the loop"

Comment: //free A0, A1, A01 matrix
    for (U32 i = 0; i < M0; ++i){
        if (i < m_L0){
            delete[] A0[i];
            A0[i] = NULL;
        }
    }

Comment: to 
    //free A0, A1, A01 matrix
    for (U32 i = 0; i < m_L0; ++i){
            delete[] A0[i];
            A0[i] = NULL;
    
    }

Comment: Sorry. Ignore above two comments. See the edit in the answer.

Comment: Why do not you set A0=NULL after line delete [] A0;

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99212/discussion-between-doptimusprime-and-user8430).

Answer (score 4):

Undefined behaviour due to overlapping/wrong ranges in [`memcpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memcpy).

Note that your code is more or less C, not C++. You can make your life a lot easier if you use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), for example:

```
typedef std::vector<U8>           vector_u8_t;
typedef std::vector<vector_u8_t>  matrix_u8_t;

matrix_u8_t A0(M0, vector_u8_t(m_L0, 0)); // (*)
```

The marked line does all allocation and initialization of the matrix for you (apart from the random values), and you also don't have to worry about freeing your memory later.

It's still not a proper matrix class, but it takes some responsibility from you.